# Composition Operators Problem

Tags: calculus

Let
A= {2,4,6,8}
B= {1,3,5,7}
C= {a,b,c,d}
F:A->C
G:B->A
F: {(2,a),(4,b),(6,c),(8,d)}
G: {(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)}

Find F o G

I tried creating a visual diagram on how to get the answer but can not figure it out since the letters in F does not connect with G. What is the correct way to answer this problem?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good... Cheers!  ref:http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6348/290189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Remember, $F\circ G$ means you first apply $G$ and then $F$ (usually read "$F$ following $G$").

$G$ maps elements of $B$ to elements of $A$, and then $F$ maps elements of $A$ to elements of $C$. So, for example, starting with the element $1\in B$, we have

$$1\stackrel{G}{\mapsto}2\stackrel{F}{\mapsto}a$$
so $F\circ G$ contains the pair $(1,a)$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes I can proceed from here, thank you for answering!